# MacBook Pro can't mount an exFAT external hard drive when having too many files

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, exfat

I need to share files between Windows and Mac, so I chose exFAT as the file system for my external hard drive.

But soon I found a serious problem, when I put too many files (like 5M) in the hard drive, OS X can't mount it. Then I have to delete them in the Windows machine, after that it works well in Mac. Does anybody know how to solve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried repairing the disk (both on Mac and Windows)?

Comment: Yes, but Mac still can not mount it.

Comment: "5M" as in 5MB of files or 5 MILLION files? If the latter you **may** have run into a file system limitation of the number of files a Mac can read on an exFAT volume (just a guess). Try putting the files in one or more folders. Then if it can see the folder(s) but not the files **in** the folders then my guess is correct.

Comment: 5 million files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSX EI Capitan solves the problem, apple fixes it in the new OS.

Answer (score 0):

In case you run into any further issues while using El Capitan and need different access between Windows/Mac file systems, you might give some 3rd-party software a try. I've had great luck with the free open-source version of [Tuxera NTFS-3G](http://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If it does not slow down the read/write speed too much, I'll give a try.